# How to change data property in Vuejs using axios when a post request is slow?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I've got a login page and in my template I have a `<p v-show="loading">Loading...</p>`

Assuming the post request doesn't have an error and is slow, then I'd like to change the loading property to true as the request is processing. How can I do that in the script below?

```
*Edit* Added the template code

<template>
  <div id="backend-view">
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
      <p v-show="loading">Loading...</p>
      <h3>Login Here</h3>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" v-model="fields.email" />
      <span v-if="errors && errors.email" class="error">{{
        errors.email[0]
      }}</span>

      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" v-model="fields.password" />
      <span v-if="errors && errors.password" class="error">{{
        errors.password[0]
      }}</span>
      <button type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: {},
      errors: {},
      loading: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      axios
        .post("/api/login", this.fields)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status == 201) {
            this.$router.push("/dashboard");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response.status == 422) {
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
          }
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observation/Suggestion **:** Before making an API call to submit the form data, You should validate the form data as per the requirement and if validation passed then only make an API call.

Now as per the answer of *I'd like to change the loading property to true as the request is processing*

On top of the above suggestion, you can make `this.loading = true` on submit and then on API response you can make it `this.loading = false`.

```
submit() {
  this.loading = true;
  axios
    .post("/api/login", this.fields)
    .then((res) => {
    this.loading = false;
    if (res.status == 201) {
      this.$router.push("/dashboard");
    }
  })
    .catch((error) => {
    this.loading = false;
    if (error.response.status == 422) {
      this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Regarding "loading..." implementation, that works. Regarding validation, I'm doing it on the backend in my controller.

```$fields = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);```

Should I validate on the front end as well?

Comment: @AlphyGacheru Yes you should also validate on frontend so that you can make an API call only if validation passes which results better performance and user experience.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a timer before calling the api which then toggles and the loading goes away.

```html
<script>

    export default {
     data() {
       return {
        fields: {},
        errors: {},
        loading: false
       };
     },
     methods: {
      submit() {
        this.loading = true
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            this.loading = false 
        }, 2000);
        axios
        .post("/api/login", this.fields)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status == 201) {
            this.$router.push("/dashboard");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response.status == 422) {
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
          }
        });
      },
     },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Setting loading to true always on submit, will display "Loading..." to the user even if for example a user clicks submit without filling the form or if they provide their email without providing the password. That would be confusing for the user in my opinion.

Comment: @AlphyGacheru I didn't know you where using form in your html, you can also prevent loading by validating the form before calling the api using `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Hey, I've edited the code and provided the template code. You can check it out, by loading I meant the p tag in the form which is available in the code now. I've modified your code by removing the timeout. So when submit is clicked we will see "loading..." text. And when we have errors in the form I've included ```this.loading=false```  below ```this.errors = error.response.data.errors;```  to hide the text. Thanks, now I have what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use async/await as bellow. This solution is perfect when you handle errors on backend.

```
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      this.loading = true;
      try{
        const res = await axios
          .post("/api/login", this.fields);
        if (res.status == 201) {
           this.$router.push("/dashboard");
        }
      }catch(error){
          if (error.response.status == 422) {
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
          }
      };
      this.loading = false;
    },
  },
```

Comment: Hey, would you kindly explain why async/await is perfect when handling errors on the backend? What exactly is making the second option better than the first option?

Comment: You can prepare your response message by server exceptions. This help you reduce codes on front (Vue.js). In this case you can forget my try/catch code too.

Comment: If I got you correct, so, the difference is the amount of code used?

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<script>
export default {
 data() {
   return {
    fields: {},
    errors: {},
    loading: false
   };
 },
 methods: {
  submit() {
    this.loading = true
    axios
    .post("/api/login", this.fields)
    .then((res) => {
        this.loading = false
      if (res.status == 201) {
        this.$router.push("/dashboard");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response.status == 422) {
        this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
      }
    });
  },
 },
 };
```

Comment: I presume you meant ```this.data=false``` .  By default it's false, so if you change it to false again I get lost. If you meant changing it to true then I had tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: I forgot to use 'this' in the loading state. loading state is set to false, will only be true if submit is called and becomes false again once your post request has response.

Comment: Hey, that will work but when the form validation fails we will have errors displayed on the form and the "loading..." will still be showing. I already fixed it from @Pouya solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).